# Photo of Person not displayed in Rich Snippet testing tool

Tags: image, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I was trying to implement a rich snippet for Google results with the `Person` object. We list out doctors and hence we chose the `Person` object. Everything works great, for example, title, address, affiliation. The only thing which doesnt work is the photo.

I have followed the instructions mentioned in http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146646 which mentions photo parameter should be used.

My Microdata code for photo is

```
<img itemprop="photo" src="http://medeasy.in/web/images/doctorImages250/y5v9fna4nx11t542s4.jpg" alt="">
```

The rich snippet testing tool does show the URL of the image for the photo parameter, however the photo isn't displayed on the rich snippet tool.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error in what you are doing. Only your interpretation of the expected behavior. You are simply telling the spiders what image is a photo of the doctor, it's up to who ever renders the result to show the image or not. Google wont show this image for instance, I don't know of any search engine that will.

<s>If you really wishes for a photo in the search result you should look in to connecting every page with the doctors Google+ profile.</s>

Comment: The last part is out of date since mid 2014, where Google dropped named feature.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

As of now Google has discontinued the authorship snippet in search result hence won't show any image from Google+ profile linked with website.

Thanks